# Why a query for a certain data type can also output other data type?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

While going through the documentation (data-types) of Apache AGE, I ran into some interesting queries that demonstrated the input/output format of data types.
Such as: -

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN 1
$$) AS (int_result agtype);
```

Which as expected outputs

```
int_result
1
(1 row)
```

However, if the query is modified to

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN 1.4
$$) AS (int_result agtype);
```

It still outputs

```
int_result
1.4
(1 row)
```

The behavior is also noticed in boolean datatype in which you can enter any numeric value, and it outputs it as it is, for an instance

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN 1.5
$$) AS (boolean_result agtype);
```

Will output

```
boolean_result
1.5
(1 row)
```

It is also interesting to note that any other input (except numeric, true, or false), for example 't' gives an error for the same boolean query.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN t
$$) AS (boolean_result agtype);
```

Will output

```
ERROR: could not find rte for t
```

I was expecting similar behavior for other inputs that did not match the data types, however, they proceeded just fine. What may be the developmental reason for such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here is that in `(int_result agtype)`, `int_result` is not the data type, but instead just the name of the column that will be displayed in the result. The data type itself is agtype, which is handled internally. AGE itself sets the correct data type for agtype.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    RETURN t
$$) AS (boolean_result agtype);
```

For this case, it gives an error because it expects to return a variable named 't'. However, since no 't' was declared in the cypher query, it throws an error.